# Integrating OpenAPI validation in Ktor tests

Tags: kotlin, openapi, ktor

I have some integration tests on the endpoints defined in my `ktor` application. I would like to validate the request and response in the test using the `OpenAPI yaml` specifications defined.

For example, if there is a header expected in the response as defined in the OpenAPI yaml file and it is missing in the actual response in the tests, `the test should fail`.

I did a lot of research on this but could not find a straightforward solution. Springboot seems to support this relatively easily. Does someone have any experience with this?

Comment: "Springboot seems to support this relatively easily" - Can you please clarify how Springboot is achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

> I have some integration tests on the endpoints defined in my ktor
> application. I would like to validate the request and response in the
> test using the OpenAPI yaml specifications defined.

Looks like you want to validate if your application is adhering to the OpenAPI specification as part of your Integration Tests. IMHO these are two separate concerns.

- Integration Tests verify if your application is able to work with its dependencies (other services, data stores, etc.)
- API Signature Validation can be done in isolation also, because you just have to verify if your application is adhering to the spec

Instead of leveraging integration tests to validate your OpenAPI, I suggest running your OpenAPI Specifications itself as a test on your application. API testing tools which support OpenAPI can generate requests and verify responses to make sure your application is adhering to the spec.

By separating these two concerns you need not have to wait for integration tests to get feedback on OpenAPI Spec validation.

> if there is a header expected in the response as defined in the
> OpenAPI yaml file and it is missing in the actual response in the
> tests, the test should fail.

You can run [OpenAPI Specification as a test](https://specmatic.in/#contract-as-test) with [Specmatic](https://specmatic.in/) to verify scenarios like this.

- [Demo video](https://youtu.be/U5Agz-mvYIU?t=39)
- [Sample springboot project](https://github.com/znsio/specmatic-order-api/blob/main/src/test/java/com/store/ContractTests.java) used in the above video
- [Documentation](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#provider-side---contract-as-a-test)

There are other tools like [Dredd](https://dredd.org/en/latest/) which seems to support Swagger 2 (Specmatic only supports OpenAPI 3.0.0 onwards). Please choose a tool that suits your need.

Hope this helps.

Disclosure: I am lead dev and CTO at Specmatic